# Setting size of plotly widgets in rmarkdown html report

Tags: r, plotly, r-markdown

I am saving `plotly` widgets and then loading them into `rmarkdown` to be used in html report. The problem is that the `plotly` widgets are too small. When I open the widgets in an external browser they are of a sufficient size, but I am unsure how to set the eize of the widgets in `rmarkdown`.

I saving `plotly` widgets using `save(p, "widget.rda")` I am then loading the widgets into `rmarkdown` using `load("widget.rda")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `out.width = "100%"` in the chunk header like so:

````
```{r out.width = "100%"}
library(leaflet)
leaflet() %>% addTiles()
```
````

[image]